# Excel Selenium VBA: Dismiss Web Selenium Pop-Up Alert

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, popup, popupwindow

Steps:

**Base URL:** https://rivcoview.rivcoacr.org/#/Property-Search

1. Select the dropdown "[image]"
2. Enter 609542017 in the Text Box
3. Click "GO" Button

When I am automating the above single action with a list of numbers and a loop. This Popup Alert occurs when I run a loop of PIN Numbers through, automating the "GO" click, then scaping the output page results. **I am trying to dismiss the resulting popup.**

No doubt, they have it triggered by some java in the background that detects my automation. I have seen several python or java possible solution examples for my problem that I can not translate to Excel VBA with Selenium. So I need a pure EXCEL VBA Selenium Solution.

```
CSS Selector for "X" button on the pop-up **= "#surveyModal > div > div > div.modal-header > button"
```

***Tried:***

```
MyBrowser.SwitchToAlert.Dismiss

Set CloseButton = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#surveyModal > div > div > div.modal-header > button").click
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still happy to get suggestions on VBA Selenium PopUps, but I have solved my problem.   My Issue ended up not being a pop-up problem.   The Element was in the DOM all along as a **hidden object**.  So the following code solved my problem:

Set SurveyButton = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#surveyModal")

If MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#surveyModal").IsDisplayed Then

```
 SurveyButton.Click
```

Else

```
GoTo 600
```

End If

600

'*******************************

I would use this as an alternative to test if the object was created.  However, since it was present but hidden all along, the code below won't work and will cause an error.

Set SurveyButton = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#surveyModal")

If Not MyBrowser.IsElementPresent(By.Css("#surveyModal")) Then

```
  SurveyButton.Click
```

Else

```
  GoTo 600
```

End If

600